# Amazon S3 java sdk - download progress

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Trying to find how to output a clean count of 0 - 100% while downloading a file from amazon. There are plenty of examples of how to do this for uploading but they don't seem to directly translate to downloads.

At the moment I'm doing the following

```
    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3Client);
    Download download = transferManager.download(s3Request, downloadedFile);

    while (!download.isDone()) {
        LOGGER.info("Downloaded >> " + download.getProgress().getPercentTransferred());
    }
```

Which does work, but it spams the console with the same value many many times (assume as it's threaded).

I know I can also do something like:

```
    ProgressListener listener = progressEvent -> LOGGER.info("Bytes transfer >> " + progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
    
    GetObjectRequest s3Request = new GetObjectRequest("swordfish-database", snapshot.getKey());
    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(s3Client);
    Download download = transferManager.download(s3Request, downloadedFile);
    
    download.addProgressListener(listener);
    download.waitForCompletion();
```

Which also works but, I loose the ease of using `download.getProgress().getPercentTransferred()`. Is this the more proper way of doing this?

Ultimately I want to be getting an int to use for a progress bar.

Comment: Well if you reserve a separate thread for progress updating then I don't see any problems with the first approach - you could just add something like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)` to update the progress every second instead of looping all the time. On the other hand in the second approach you only have to divide `getBytesTransferred()` by `getBytes()` to get percentage which also doesn't seem too difficult :-)

Comment: Oh of course! for some reason my head was thinking that sleeping would sleep the actual download (hence slowing things down) which is why I didn't do it in the first place. Brain fart on my half. Happy to accept this as an answer if you write one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you reserve a separate thread for progress updating then I don't see any problems with the first approach - you could just add something like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)` to update the progress every second instead of looping all the time. On the other hand in the second approach you only have to divide `getBytesTransferred()` by `getBytes()` to get percentage which also doesn't seem too difficult :-)